# Shopware custom plugin not generating public folder

Tags: plugins, public, shopware

i tested this shopware plugin

https://github.com/shopware/swag-docs-new-tab

which is linked from official shopware documentation here

https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-platform-dev-en/how-to/new-tab-admin?category=shopware-platform-dev-en/how-to

`./psh.phar administration:build` command should `rebuild` public folder under plugin and then copy created folder under `public/bundles`

this is not happening

what can be issue that `public` folder isnt created ? any recommendation how to track where is the problem ? i dont see anything usefull in log. 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like it is an issue with the read/write permissions on your filesystem. Perhaps you need to check the ownership of the folders (it should be the user that executes your php process).

Otherwhise you could create it manually:

```
.../src/Resources/public/administration

.../src/Resources/public/storefront
```

Comment: hi rotfuchs,  but i tried also another plugin which is linked from official documentation called SwagAdministrationNewField and that one is generating public folder correctly.   SwagNewTab has path src/Resources/app/administration/src/pagge while SwagAdministrationNewField has path src/Resources/administration/src/extension.  not sure why is there difference.  also that public folder should contain minified js file, so is there any command with which i can generate this ?  thanks

Comment: also i am using shopware with docker, so guess there shouldnt be any differences in permissions

Comment: looks that there is issue with plugin structure in SwagNewTab. i reformated  it to follow same structure like SwagAdministrationNewField and its working now